# How to simulate the gravity of a bunch of planets on an object?

Tags: simulation

I'm trying to simulate an object, like a ship, floating around planets. all i can find about anything like this online is the N-body problem, but I'm not trying to simulate the effects of the planets on each other, only on the "ship".

i intend to fake the orbits of the planets to save resources, and the affect of the ship on the planets is negligible, i only wanna simulate the worthwhile things.

my current method defines the force of gravity on the ship as 1/distance, then averages all the gravity vectors to get the final gravity vector for the ship. this doesn't do what i want though. the ship can't maintain a stable orbit around a planet, and ends up flying away, it also ends up gaining energy as it goes on.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! I don't feel like you will get an answer here, we needed more details on what you're trying to build such as the code you wrote so far. Beyond that, I'd recommend you to try [Physics StackExchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com) instead. You may get better help there. Good luck!

Comment: Gravitational force is 1/r^2; forces add, not average (since otherwise adding a zero-mass object would reduce the effect of the others).

Comment: @MiguelCardoso If any game programmers at all hang out at SO, the poster will be fine. This is game simulation 101.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's very close to the n-body problem. Solutions to the n-body problem compute the force between each pair of bodies (with Newton's expression for the gravitational force between two masses; it's inversely proportional to the *square* of the distance), sums up those forces as vectors for each body, then integrates all the equations of motion a[i] = F[i]/m[i] to update positions x[i] as time varies.

In your case you'll do exactly the same thing except you'll fix the bodies you don't want to move. Consequently it's useless to compute forces between pairs of those fixed bodies: they always have acceleration and velocity zero. You'll compute only forces between two movable bodies and between a movable one and a fixed one. Then sum up all the forces on each movable body and proceed to integrate one equation for each of them.

In the simplest case you have only one movable body.  So you'll compute the force between it and each fixed one. Add up all these vector forces, and proceed as before. There will be only one vector equation F=ma.

The problems you're describing are almost certainly due to unstable integration.  If you're using simple Euler, the time step needs to be *extremely* small.  To allow bigger steps, switch to a more sophisticated scheme. Runge-Kutta is a common choice, but there are others.